# django: cannot import name SimpleListFilter

Tags: importerror, django-admin-filters

I have the code form [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), but this will output an error.

> ImportError: cannot import name SimpleListFilter

I am using django 1.3

Anyone knows what's problem with this import?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that SimpleListFilter was added in Django 1.4. If you look at the documentation for [Django 1.3 Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) no mention is made of it.

Comment: then how can i do this in django 1.3 ?

Comment: i want to use list_filter, having custom list ranges?? is there any solution in 1.3 version?

Comment: You should maybe ask that with another question as your original question has been answered.

Comment: Andre is right, but just searching through the 1.3 page for "filter", it may have something similar: ModelAdmin.list_filter.  That may be a good starting point on google.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the dev docs.  If you jump to the top of the page and click on 1.3, you'll see that model isn't available in your version.